# Handle erroneous JS when loading page in Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I was scraping a site recently, and ran into this:

`<img onerror="onErrorImg(this)" onload="onLoadImg(this);" src="example.png">`

However, the site in question does not define a function named `onErrorImg`, so this produces an error in the console if images are disabled. I'd like to disable images in this case as it's being run over a metered connection. Without changing the rest of my code, if I enable images in the browser, the page loads correctly & can be scraped.

I'm going to contact the site owners about this, but in the event it isn't rectified in a timely manner: Is there a straightforward workaround for cases like this? If I could inject a JS script into the DOM as it's being loaded, I could define a function that is just an empty block, but beyond that I'm not really sure how to approach this.

Edit: I'm not sure what the process is that creates the DOM elements for that page, but if you use `requests` to fetch the URL, it primarily only returns JS. This makes me assume that the whole of the page is generated via JS / AJAX, so this function error'ing out seems to cause the majority of the page not to load.

Answer (score 0):

try with this simple solution, it overwriting the function

```
driver.get('https://.....')

driver.execute_script('''
    window.onErrorImg = function(){}
    window.onLoadImg = function(){}
''')
```

if it not working you have to create extension that overwrite the function early.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but even if I send this script immediately after "getting" the page, it seemed to apply too late. For the time being, I'm allowing the page to render with images & once they've appeared in the DOM, I'm fetching their SRC's & redirecting to "about:blank" so as to minimize the bandwidth impact. When you say "create extension", do you mean a browser extension written to run if Firefox tries to generate the page?